# Angular 6 looping through child form Controls to patch form

Tags: angular, angular6, nativescript

im try to patch child form arrays and am having trouble looping through the child arrays. My form get the name and type properties but i can't get the reps and weight values into the form,
im getting a  Cannot read property 'setParent' of undefined error, below the are two way i have tried to solve this problem but i am having no luck,

```
  setValueForm() {
    let setMultipliers = this.patchedMultipers.setMultipliers;


    const formArray = new FormArray([]);

    setMultipliers.forEach(s => {
      formArray.push(this.fb.group({
        name: s.name,
        reps: this.setNewReps(s), //pretty much just pushes a new form control
        weights: this.setNewWeight(s)
      }));
    });

    this.multiplerForm.setControl('setMultipliers', formArray)

    this.multiplerForm.patchValue(this.patchedMultipers);
  }
```

```
private initForm() {
    let type: '';
    let setMultipliers = new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(''),
        reps: new FormArray([]),
        weights: new FormArray([])
      })
    ]);

    if (this.editMode) {
      this.programService.getprogramMultiplierSubject().subscribe(res => {
        this.multipliers = res,
          this.patchedMultipliers = this.multipliers[this.index];
        console.log("from editmode", this.patchedMultipliers);

        type = this.patchedMultipliers.type;

        if (this.patchedMultipliers['setMultipliers']) {
          for (let setMultiplier of this.patchedMultipliers.setMultipliers) {
            setMultipliers.push(
              new FormGroup({
                'name': new FormControl(setMultiplier.name),
                'reps': setMultiplier.reps.forEach(rep => {
                   new FormControl(rep)
                })

              })
            )
          }
        }
      })
    }


    this.multiplierForm = new FormGroup({
      'type': new FormControl(type),
      setMultipliers: setMultipliers
    });

  }
```

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <form [formGroup]="multiplierForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <Button text="Save"></Button>
            <Button text="Cancel"></Button>
            <Button text="Add Multiplier" (tap)="onAddMultiplier()"></Button>

            <Label text="type"></Label>
            <TextField formControlName="type"></TextField>

            <StackLayout formArrayName="setMultipliers" *ngFor="let setMultiplier of multiplierForm.get('setMultipliers').controls; let i = index;">
                <StackLayout [formGroupName]="i">
                    <!-- <Label text="name"></Label>
                    <TextField formControlName="name"></TextField> -->
                    <TextField  class="hidden" #NameEl  height="1" formControlName="name" text="Multipler Week {{2 + i}}" ></TextField>   
                    <Label android:fontSize="20" text="{{NameEl.text}}"></Label>

                    <StackLayout formArrayName="reps" *ngFor="let rep of setMultiplier.get('reps').controls; let k = index">
                        <Label  text="Set for reps {{k+1}}" ></Label>
                        <TextField [formControlName]="k"></TextField>
                        <Button  text="X" (tap)="removeReps(setMultiplier.controls.reps,j)"></Button>

                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout formArrayName="weights" *ngFor="let weight of setMultiplier.get('weights').controls; let j = index">
                        <Label text="Set for weight {{j+1}}" ></Label>
                        <TextField [formControlName]="j"></TextField>
                        <Button  text="X" (tap)="removeWeights(setMultiplier.controls.weights,k)"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <Button text="Add Rep" (tap)="addReps(setMultiplier.controls.reps)"></Button>
                    <Button text="Add Weights" (tap)="addWeights(setMultiplier.controls.weights)"></Button>
                    <Button (tap)="onDeleteMultiplier(i)" text="Delete Multiplier"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </form>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: When exactly you are hitting this error, while patching values?

Comment: yeah it will patch the type and the name  and will create form controls of the amount of reps being patched but it wont put the values in so im guessing it breaks when patching the rep values

Comment: Can you show some sample data, how `patchedMultipers` look like.

Comment: {
   "type": "Working Set",
   "setMultipliers": [
     {
       "name": "Multipler Week 2",
       "reps": [
         "2",
        "2",
         "0",
         "0"
       ],
       "weights": []
     },
     {
       "name": "Multipler Week 3",
       "reps": [
         "0",
         "0",
         "2",
         "2"
       ],
       "weights": []
    },
     {
       "name": "Multipler Week 4",
       "reps": [
         "0",
         "2",
         "0",
         "2"
       ],
       "weights": []
     }
   ]
 }

Comment: Have you registered any element as `form`, there is no equivalent of HTML form in NativeScript. Can clean it up and setup a Playground sample?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=wWb85p   

Its patched the type and sets out the reps controls but doesnt patch the actual values and then breaks and doesnt set out the rest of the form , probably missing something simple but cant see it :( haha thanks for the interest

Comment: You just have to pass the controls before accessing it, seems good on my end - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=wWb85p&v=2